# O que são filas (queue) do Oracle

Tags: oracle, fila, oracle18c

Estava trabalhando em uma importação de banco de dados Oracle, e durante a importação reparei a existência de objetos do tipo `queue`, estou acostumado com `procedures`,`functions`,`view`, etc. Esse em questão nunca tinha visto.

Gostaria de saber mais sobre esse tipo `queue` de objeto, como:

1. Para que são utilizadas?
2. Como criar uma fila `queue`?

Obrigado